# Can an EB-3C Unskilled Green Card holder do Software Engineering work?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, greencard

Can an EB-3C Unskilled Green Card holder lawfully do Software Engineering work? (May it be part-time or full-time)

Is there going to be a problem if the old job and the new job’s nature and description are different? For example, being on an employment based EB-3c unskilled Green Card holder working as a cleaning technician/janitor, I want to change employment from being a cleaning technician/janitor to a Software Engineer (my original work in my home country). Hoping for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

A green card holder can do any sort of work unless the job requires US citizenship (for example, certain government-related jobs require security clearance and therefore US citizenship).

If the EB-3C application presented the applicant as not having any skills, when in fact the person was an experienced software engineer, then the application may have been fraudulent, and working as a software engineer could expose the fraud, which could lead to a finding of deportability.  But this seems unlikely, and I cannot think of any other way in which the proposed job would cause problems.